# Avro enum symbol with space character

Tags: schema, avro

I have the following json file

```
{"product": "RGAS chair",
"company": "RGA GmbH"}
```

and I want to check if the value for the Company attribute is from a finite set of values
so my avro schema for this json file is:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "test",
    "namespace": "test",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "product","type":"string"},
        {"name": "company","type":{"name": "suit_value_company", "type":"enum","symbols":[ "RGA GmbH", "DKT SA", "ABBV GmbH"]}}
            ]
}
```

When I validate my file, I encounter a problem with a space in symbols.
How can I validate the values with space in avro schema ?

Comment: The [Avro specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Enums) says enum symbols cannot have spaces. Symbols must match the regular expression `[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*`

Comment: Thanks for the information